# Make text inside textarea not break to next line

Tags: html, css

So I have a textarea and when you put too much next on one line, it overflows and goes onto the next line, without being on the next line.

This is normal but what if I want it to not go onto the next line and keep going, possibly with a scroll bar so you can scroll across to view the text

For example

```
text here flows onto
the next line
```

I want it to be

```
text here doesnt flow onto the next line, but might not be visible without scrolling
```

In a `textarea`

Is this possible? I've tried overflow-x but that doesn't seem to be working

Comment: Why not just use an `input`?

Comment: I need it to be multiline, makes more sense making it a `textarea`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by applying the css - `white-space: nowrap` rule.

```css
textarea {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
```

Comment: thank you! this and `white-space: pre;` works

Comment: @TheSavageTeddy, Yes, but `white-space: nowrap` is more logical to use for your task! Since `white-space: pre` is more suitable for text with spaces and hyphens, as it was styled in the html code. Also, the analogue is the `<pre>` tag.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `white-space: nowrap;` CSS property along with the `overflow`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Answer (score 1):

Set `white-space: pre;` to the textarea

```css
textarea {
  white-space: pre
}
```

```html
<textarea cols="50" rows="2"></textarea>
```